# Why AngularJS $scope is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in AngularJS, I want to create an array and post it to server by `register` function, here's Controller code:

```
root.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.lineItems = [];
    $scope.addItem = function (id) {
        $scope.lineItems.push(id);
        console.log($scope.lineItems);
        // gives me right data -> Array [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "1" ]
    };
    $scope.register = function () {
        // post data to server
        console.log($scope.lineItems);
        // gives me an empty array -> Array [ ]
    };
});
```

Here's HTML code and directives:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
    <a ng-click="register()"></a>

    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <a class="btn" ng-click="addItem(product.id)">Add</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem occurs when i want to call `register` function, it gives me an empty array instead of array elements while it's not gonna happen in `addItem` function.

Comment: when you click on the anchor tag, does it console.log  properly?

Comment: What do you mean by anchor tag?

Comment: <a> is an anchor tag

Comment: Yes! addItem function logs correctly.

Comment: try changing the function name register to something else like regista

Comment: when u call register() function???

Comment: How are you calling `register` function?

Comment: I'm calling register this way <a ng-click="register()"></a>

Comment: Could you share a copy of the code in a Plunker? From what you've shown, everything should be working as expected.

Comment: @wateriswet I changed function name now nothing happens!

Comment: your code work correctly . may be you call it before addItem!!???

Comment: may be you make empty it. check your code agian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code and work correctly.

```js
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope){
  
    $scope.products = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}];
  
  $scope.lineItems = [];
    $scope.addItem = function (id) {
        $scope.lineItems.push(id);
        console.log($scope.lineItems);
        // gives me right data
    };
    $scope.register = function () {
        // post data to server
        console.log($scope.lineItems);
        // gives me an empty array
    };

  
 
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
   <a ng-click="register()">Register</a>

<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <a class="btn" ng-click="addItem(product.id)">Add : {{product.id}}</a>
</div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I think I made a simple mistake.